# Wiremock Server not able to store recordings in a specified directory

Tags: java, server, wiremock

I want to run a wiremock server in recording mode and store all the recordings in a specific folder but I cannot succeed to do this. I use the following code :

```
WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(WireMockConfiguration.options()
            .port(8091).usingFilesUnderDirectory("src/main/resources")
            .notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true)));
    wireMockServer.start();
    wireMockServer.startRecording(
            recordSpec()
                    .forTarget("a specific host")
                    .makeStubsPersistent(true)

    );
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong. I don't want to use the standalone version because I want to run multiple instances in parallel in a java manner.